# How to run spring project offline mode?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am trying to run a Spring Project, with several dependencies, that I have already downloaded into my local repository, and have also done followings :

1. Added local repository path in setting.xml in localRepository tag.
2. Running the project using mvn install -nsu -llr -o , for offline mode.

And I am getting following error :

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project file2Json: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project
>   com.nse.file2Json:file2Json:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Cannot access central
>   (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-csv:jar:2.8.4 has
>   not been downloaded from it before. -> [Help 1]

I have the dependency installed, take a look :(
[image]

I have following questions :

1. Why is the project is trying to look into http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 when I am using offline mode ?
2. How can I run the project offline, by providing the required dependencies at required paths ?
   Please help !
   thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It says it cannot access Maven Central because you are in offline mode. And it tries to look there, because ´jackson-dataformat-csv` is not in your local repository, so Maven needs to get it from somewhere (and Maven Central is the default repository).

What you need to do is to execute `mvn dependency:go-offline` before you switch to the offline mode. This will download everything that you need (dependencies, transitive dependencies as well as plugins).

Comment: Well, Maven cannot find it, so to what path have you downloaded the dependency? And have you included all transitive dependencies?

Comment: Ok, you have added the pom and the sources.jar, but not the jar with the compiled binaries. Maven needs that.